# OS X: Update bash version for root user

Tags: bash, macos

Small prerequisite: I am on OS X, the bash version shipped with it is some old 3.x version. Since I required some modern features, I updated to 4.x some time ago.

I have written a script that works fine when executed as current user, but fails when run as root through a plist file/launchd.

This is because I apparently only updated the bash version for my user, not root.

How can I update bash for the root user aswell, and is it safe to do so?

Another option would of cause be to just use a "custom" shebang that points to my updated bash version, but this seems to be a bit hacky since it is guaranteed to fail on other systems.

I also know about the `UserName` key for plist files, but unfortunately when executing as my user, the script doesn't event get called (probably some path issue I guess). I was hoping a bash updating would be the more elegant solution.

Comment: There's no guarantee what version of `bash` you get with `#!/bin/bash`; shebangs are for convenience, not strict portability. If you want portability, you target POSIX shell with `#!/bin/sh`; otherwise you adjust the shebang on a per-machine basis as needed.

Answer (score 1):

macOS ships with bash v3 in /bin/bash. You should not attempt to replace this (or any file in /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, or /usr/sbin); System Integrity Protection will prevent it, and overriding that is a bad idea. As a result, scripts using a `#!/bin/bash` should always run under bash v3.

One thing you could do is create /usr/local/bin, install bash v4 there, and then use a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. /usr/local/bin is listed first in the default path in macOS (despite not existing by default), so that shebang should use the new bash under all accounts.

Just in case, I'd add a version check to the script, before it uses any v4 features. Something like this:

```
if [ "${BASH_VERSINFO:-0}" -lt 4 ]; then
    echo "This script ($0) requires bash version 4 or later" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```